# How to Deploy React app with server on heroku?

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I am deploying a React app to Heroku. On my local machine, I have my react folder and I have a server folder so that I can make API calls to log people in. Normally I run `npm start` in my react folder and then open a separate terminal to and run `node server.js`. This way I can use my app and log in.

The problem is that when I deploy to heroku I only see my app. How do I get heroku to run my server.js file as well? I have done it before but that was a year ago.

Here is the git repo for my app: https://github.com/budstamper/WebChop
The server.js is in the parent folder and the app is in the 'client' folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your repo link takes to me to a 404 error so could not see your file. I use a devDependency called `concurrently` to run my app folder and `server.js` on one terminal. Here is how i deploy to heroku with the `concurrently` dependency.

```
`    "scripts": {
"client": "cd client && npm run start",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"build": "cd client && npm run build",
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
"start": "node server.js",
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
```

`

Comment: I made the repo public, I added your scripts to my package.json but now I get an infinite loop of "remote:        > webchop@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_2fbdd6fb6d90cdd527cd3d27ddcb358d
remote:        > cd client && npm run build" in my terminal when pushing to heroku